# Passing command with args to subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, python-3.x

Following script works fine when I try passing a batch file (that doesn't require any arguments) to the function.

```
script_as_var = os.path.join(os.environ['SOME_VAR'], 'bin/stop.bat')
jboss = os.path.join(os.environ['JBOSS_HOME'], 'bin/jboss-cli.bat')

def status(some_arg, cmd, more_arg):
    print('CMD: ' + cmd)
    ps = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = ps.communicate()[0]
    ...
    ...

status(10, script_as_var, 'last_arg')   # Works fine
```

However, when I try passing below command to the function, it fails.

```
status(15, '[jboss,'"'-c'"','"'--commands="'"read-attribute server-state"'"'"']',
       'some_arg')
```

Output:

```
CMD: [jboss,'-c','--commands='"read-attribute server-state"'']
...
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Below command used to work fine when I didn't create a function.

```
ps = subprocess.Popen([jboss,'-c','--commands='"read-attribute server-state"''],
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

As you can notice from the output of `print` command, I was successfully able to somehow (by using the messy single and double quotes combination) pass the exact command that I was able to run when this function was not created but it seems it sill needs some work for `jboss` variable to expand.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Umm, you realize that you're supposed to pass a *list* to `subprocess.Popen`, not a string that *looks* like a list?

Comment: I see this post has been `put on hold`. It says, "...this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers". As i have just started learning Python, there may be many others who might commit the same mistake i did so I'm not sure why this post may not be of help for others.

Comment: There might be someone who makes the same mistake as you once in a blue moon, but what's *far* more likely is that your question will attract views from people who have a completely different problem. Especially with a title like that, which has no relation to the problem whatsoever (the problem isn't related to *functions* at all). I honestly think this question will do more harm than good.

Comment: I got the point that it has nothing exactly to do with _functions_ but when this issue came up, i was not sure what else to mention as the post title. I was searching for solutions using those keywords only. If you feel removing the `function` keyword makes it more relevant to the problem i faced, i think you can remove it or i can do the needful. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) constructor will accept either a string or a sequence like a `list` as its first argument named *`args`*. You code appears to be trying to use both...and here's how to do that correctly. As you can see, it's also expanding the `jboss` variable as desired.

```
import os
os.environ['SOME_VAR'] = 'some_var'          # For testing
os.environ['JBOSS_HOME'] = 'jboss_home_var'  # For testing

script_as_var = os.path.join(os.environ['SOME_VAR'], 'bin/stop.bat')
jboss = os.path.join(os.environ['JBOSS_HOME'], 'bin/jboss-cli.bat')

def status(some_arg, cmd, more_arg):
    print('CMD: ' + repr(cmd))
#    ps = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
#    output = ps.communicate()[0]
#    ...
#    ...

status(10, script_as_var, 'last_arg')
status(15, [jboss, '-c', '--commands="read-attribute server-state"'], 'some_arg')
```

Output:

```
CMD: 'some_var\\bin/stop.bat'
CMD: ['jboss_home_var\\bin/jboss-cli.bat', '-c', '--commands="read-attribute server-state"']
```

Comment: Upvoted both the answers. I got the mistake i was committing. By the way, use of `repr` was nice. Just read about it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a `str` for command. Note that your working example has a `list`. You just need to get rid of all the extra quoting and pass a list.

```
>>> def foo(a, b, c):
  print(b) 

>>> jboss = 42

>>> foo(15,'[jboss,'"'-c'"','"'--commands="'"read-attribute server-state"'"'"']','some_arg')
[jboss,'-c','--commands="read-attribute server-state"']

>>> foo(15,[jboss,'-c','--commands="read-attribute server-state"'],'some_arg')
[42, '-c', '--commands="read-attribute server-state"']
```